# First JSP + Glassfish app

Tags: jsp, glassfish

I'm very beginner, I tried to make JSP application HelloWorld, very simple like on the youtube video here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_33ZHYCjf8&feature=related, without changing almost anything

But on my computer I can't even start this simple HelloWorld application getting the error "Not found: The requested URL /HelloWorld/ was not found on this server"

I use Windows 7, Netbeans 6.9.1 and Glassfish v.3.

In WEB-INF directory I have only sun-web.xml like this:

```
<sun-web-app error-url="">
  <context-root>/HelloWorld</context-root>
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

Please, can you direct me, what with this problem could be connected and what I can check, all the answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Given your `sun-web.xml`, the URL should be something like `yourhost/SayHello` and **not** `yourhost/HelloWorld`.

Comment: Yes, it is. Actually I tried the second time to be sure to make this simple app, fisrt with the name HelloWorld and second with SayHello, I know, that it should not change anything and it has not changed. So just every time I make the same way HelloWorld app, I get the same error and I don't know how to tackle it. But I will edit initial post to make it proper way with one name. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @user914102: You know whether the app started or not (you should see something in the logs)?

Comment: In the log of application I see:

Comment: init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
Starting GlassFish Server 3
GlassFish Server 3 is running.
Incrementally deploying HelloWorld
Completed incremental distribution of HelloWorld
run-deploy:
Browsing: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/
run-display-browser:
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 38 seconds)

Comment: and there are no any warnings or errors in Java DB or Glassfish log window in Netbeans